# Assigning variables information from a infile txt C++

Tags: c++, string

This is my text file:

> ```
> 12345 shoe 5 0   
> 34534 foot 72 1   
> 34562 race 10 0 
> 34672 chicken 24 150
> 88 pop 65 0
> ```

I need to take this file and go row by row, assign the first number as an identifier `itemNum`, second word as `itemName`, third number as `itemPrice`, and last number as `itemAdjusmentValue`. I will need to perform arithmetic with the last two numbers `itemPrice` and `itemAdjusmentValue`.

Code so far:

```
using namespace std;

// making a struct to store each value of the cuadre

struct Cuadre 
{

    int itemNum;
    string itemName;
    int itemPrice;
    int itemAdjusment;

};

int main (){

    ifstream infile("sheet_1.txt");
    string checkLine;

    if (infile.is_open()){

        while ( infile.good()){

            getline (infile, checkLine);
            cout << checkLine << endl;
        }
    }
    else 
        cout << "error with name of file" << endl;


    vector<Cuadre> procedures;

    Cuadre line;

    while(Cuadre >> line.itemNum >> line.itemName >> line.itemPrice >> line.itemAdjusment){
        procedures.push_back(line);
    }
```

This code generates an error on the last while statement

> expected primary-expression before '>>' token

I cant really find a specific tutorial on how to do this, and i've looked a good amount.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `checkLine >>`?

Comment: And it should be inside the loop that reads from the file. Otherwise you're just processing the last line.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Already corrected it in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you posted, (with reference to the `>>` [istream operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)) it looks like you want to stream the contents of the string data read from your file into the members of a struct.

It is not possible to stream directly from a `std::string` (eg: `checkLine >> x >> y >> z`), as string does not provide a streaming interface.

In order to do that you need to use a stream, such as [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream).
You could populate a  with your string `checkLine`, and then stream from that into your data members

```
std::stringstream ss(checkLine);
ss >> line.itemNum >> line.itemName >> line.itemPrice >> line.itemAdjusment;
```

**Example code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

// making a struct to store each value of the cuadre

struct Cuadre
{

    int itemNum;
    string itemName;
    int itemPrice;
    int itemAdjusment;

};

int main (){

    ifstream infile("sheet_1.txt");
    string checkLine;

    vector<Cuadre> procedures;

    if (infile.is_open()){

        while ( infile.good()){

            getline (infile, checkLine);
            cout << checkLine << endl;

            Cuadre line;
            std::stringstream ss(checkLine);
            ss >> line.itemNum >> line.itemName >> line.itemPrice >> line.itemAdjusment;
            procedures.push_back(line);
        }
    }
    else
        cout << "error with name of file" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i figured it out

Comment: @TentacleSlinger in order to get an answer to that you should post another question. SO is not a forum, it's one-question-per-post style site

Comment: im trying to figure out how to delete that i just figured it out.

Comment: `while ( infile.good()){` is wrong (what happens if the file has a blank line at the end?) See the link at the end of Barmar's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to push into the vector inside the loop that reads from the file. And you should be getting the fields from `checkLine` -- `Cuadre` is a type name, not a variable you can read from. But to do that you need to create a `stringstream`.

```
int main (){

    ifstream infile("sheet_1.txt");
    string checkLine;
    vector<Cuadre> procedures;

    if (infile.is_open()){

        while (getline (infile, checkLine)){
            Cuadre line;
            cout << checkLine << endl;
            stringstream linestream(checkline);
            if (linestream >> line.itemNum >> line.itemName >> line.itemPrice >> line.itemAdjusment) {
                procedures.push_back(line);
            } else {
                cout << "incorrect line" << endl;
                break;
            }                
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "error with name of file" << endl;
    }
}
```

`while (infile.good())` is also not correct, it's essentially the same as `while (!infile.eof())`. See [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: `std::string` does not offer a streaming interface. You'll need to populate a stringstream first, and use that

Comment: thanks, fixed. For some reason I thought something like this had been added to the language (using the extract operator with a string would create the stream automatically).

Answer (score 1):

You can try reading directly into struct as well:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Cuadre
{
    int itemNum;
    std::string itemName;
    int itemPrice;
    int itemAdjusment;
};

int main() 
{
    std::vector<Cuadre> procedures;
    std::ifstream infile("sheet_1.txt");

    while (infile)
    {
        Cuadre line;
        if (infile >> line.itemNum >> line.itemName >> line.itemPrice >> line.itemAdjusment)
            procedures.push_back(line);
        else
            break;
    }

    if (!procedures.empty())
    {
        for (auto &p : procedures)
            std::cout
            << "itemNum: " << p.itemNum << "\t"
            << "itemName: " << p.itemName << "\t"
            << "itemPrice: " << p.itemPrice << "\t"
            << "itemAdjusment: " << p.itemAdjusment
            << std::endl;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "error with file or data" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
itemNum: 12345  itemName: shoe  itemPrice: 5    itemAdjusment: 0
itemNum: 34534  itemName: foot  itemPrice: 72   itemAdjusment: 1
itemNum: 34562  itemName: race  itemPrice: 10   itemAdjusment: 0
itemNum: 34672  itemName: chicken       itemPrice: 24   itemAdjusment: 150
itemNum: 88     itemName: pop   itemPrice: 65   itemAdjusment: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you define an overload of `>>` for your type `Cuadre`, you can read directly from the file into `Cuadre` objects.

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Cuadre & cuadre)
{
    std::string s;
    getline(is, s);
    std::cout << s;
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    ss >> cuadre.itemNum >> cuadre.itemName >> cuadre.itemPrice >> cuadre.itemAdjusment;
    return is;

    // or without logging

    return is >> cuadre.itemNum >> cuadre.itemName >> cuadre.itemPrice >> cuadre.itemAdjusment;
}

int main (){

    ifstream infile("sheet_1.txt");
    vector<Cuadre> procedures;

    for (Cuadre line; infile >> line;) {
        procedures.push_back(line);
    }

    // or with #include <algorithm>

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<Cuadre>{ infile }, {}, std::back_inserter(procedures));
}
```

Comment: This is nice code. The only improvement I'd make is to make the `operator>>` overload read into a local `Cuadre` (or into four local variables)  and then set the members of `cuadre`, so that the `cuadre` parameter is only populated if all fields can be read successfully.